# What would be the logical equivalence of not P or T?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I'm finishing my prove but is the logical equivalence of not P OR T equal to True?
This is what I'm trying to prove $$(p \land q) \implies q $$

Comment: Can you show your proof?

Comment: That is what I am trying to prove

Comment: Have you used implication definition?

Comment: yes I'm just stuck on the last part I don't know if notP and T equals True

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**:$(p \land q) \implies q$ is same with $\neg p \lor \neg q \lor q$

Comment: Yes I have that then I get not P or True, is that equal to True?

Comment: You can use that $x \lor T = T$ for any $x$.